# Issue with mod rewites in htaccess on Apache

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using a private host, linux php, where the htaccess just does not act like it does with the bigger famous top 10 hosts etc.

```
redirect 301 /pagea.html /pageb.html
```

Causes a 500 internal error on my host, and works fine on other hosts.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.site\.net$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.site.net/ [L,R=301]
```

Works fine on my host (and others) so I am presuming this is a proof the mod_rewite is on

These 2 commands dont work and dont give 500 error:

```
redirect 301 http://www.site.net/a/page.php http://www.site.net/page.php
RewriteRule ^/a/page.php$ /page.php [R=301,L]
```

Would anyone guess what the issue is, and how to get the rewrites working like they do everywhere else?

Comment: Check your logs -- what's the error? What OS is the "private" host running? Same for the "famous" host. What version of Apache? Are you sure mod_alias is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server wasnt giving permissions for the rewrites.  But this information was not available.